# Trying to alert message on change of a select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm playing around with jQuery, and am having some trouble alerting a message on change of my select drop down element:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>       
    </head>

    <body>

        <div>
            <select id="fruits">
                <option selected>Choose a fruit</option>
                <option name="orange">Orange</option>
                <option name="mango">Mango</option>     
            </select>
        </div>

    </body>


</html>
```

my js:

```
$('#fruits').on('change', function() {
    alert('Hello!');
});
```

When I run this in Chrome, I don't get any warnings in my console, and changing the select option does nothing. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: wrap jquery code inside document.ready() and its working see here   http://jsfiddle.net/2zmxyx6n/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code in document ready:

```
$(function () {
    $('#fruits').on('change', function() {
        alert('Hello!');
    });
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fxgeqanc/).

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

1.you must call js function or you can write code in ready function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>  
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#fruits').on('change', function() {
        alert('Hello!');
    });
    });
        </script>     
    </head>

    <body>

        <div>
            <select id="fruits">
                <option selected>Choose a fruit</option>
                <option name="orange">Orange</option>
                <option name="mango">Mango</option>     
            </select>
        </div>

    </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this too:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>  

    </head>

    <body>

        <div>
            <select id="fruits">
                <option selected>Choose a fruit</option>
                <option name="orange">Orange</option>
                <option name="mango">Mango</option>     
            </select>
        </div>
       <script>

        $('#fruits').on('change', function() {
        alert('Hello!');
    });

        </script>  
    </body>


</html>
```